# Erosion and Dilated getting swapped

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I tried using morphological operations: Erosion and Dilation using skimage module. However, the results seem interchanged for me. Dilation should add pixels to the boundaries and erosion should remove them. But in my case, it is happening just the opposite.

Code:

```
from skimage import data, morphology
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot_comparison(original, first, second, title1, title2):
    fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10,8))
    ax1.imshow(original, cmap='gray')
    ax1.set_title('Original')
    ax1.axis('off')
    ax2.imshow(first, cmap='gray')
    ax2.set_title(title1)
    ax2.axis('off')
    ax3.imshow(second, cmap='gray')
    ax3.set_title(title2)
    ax3.axis('off')
    plt.show()

selem = morphology.rectangle(12, 6)

horse = data.horse()
eroded = morphology.binary_erosion(horse, selem=selem)
dilated = morphology.binary_dilation(horse, selem=selem)

plot_comparison(horse, eroded, dilated, 'Eroded', 'Dilated')
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: The white part is the "object" part. In the dilation, the white part grows. The horse is the "background" part, and therefore shrinks under the dilation.

Comment: So, for these types of images, is it preferred to use an inverted threshold and then morphing techniques?

Comment: Yes, just invert the image.